# Finding the volume enclosed by two surfaces of revolution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, geometry

I've come this far as to combine both functions in a graph:

```
f = Plot[4 - x^2, {x, -10, 10}]
g = Plot[-1 + 4 x, {x, -10, 10}]
Show[g, f, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Solved the intersections:

```
sol = x /. NSolve[f == g, x, Reals]
```

> {-5., 1.}

Next thing I would like to do is integrate and rotate the area between the intersects enclosed by the functions around the X axis and calculate the volume of the resulting rotational body.
I'm fairly new to Mathematica and require some help to finish the plot.

EDIT:
I have painted the area, so it is clear which area is meant to be revolved:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rotate the region". Do you want to create a solid of revolution using the region between the two curves?  If yes, which axis are you rotating around?

Comment: 1) I think you want `4 - x^2` rather than `4 - x`. 2) What line in 3D space to want as the axis of revolution?

Comment: @Szabolcs around the X axis. I mean the Area, the 2 functions are enclosing between the intersections.
Do you have an idea how to plot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an answer, but an explanation of why the question, as currently posed, is not clear.

If the two curves are rotated about the x-axis, they do not enclose a simple closed region -- they produce as region that self-intersects and for which it is difficult to define volume. Here are two views of a half-revolution plot that show the difficulty of determining the volume.

[image: plots]

However, if the two curves are translated upward by 21, then revolving them about the x-axis produces a simple closed region for which has a volume that can be computed with reasonable effort.

[image: simple_plot]

Is volume enclosed by the translated curves the one you want?

#### Update

Code for producing the half-revolution plots

```
f[x_] := 4 - x^2
g[x_] := -1 + 4 x
fSurface = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, -5, 1}, {u, 0, π}, 
    ColorFunction -> (White &), RevolutionAxis -> "X"];
gSurface = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[g[x], {x, -5, 1}, {u, 0, π}, 
    ColorFunction -> (White &), RevolutionAxis -> "X"];
Show[
  fSurface, gSurface,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

This may be the answer you are looking for. I will solve the problem by translating the curves.

The functions after  translating the curves upward by 21.

```
f[x_] := 25 - x^2
g[x_] := 20 + 4 x
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 1}]
```

[image: 2Dplot]

The surfaces of revolution

```
fSurface = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, -5, 1}, {u, 0, 2 π}, 
    ColorFunction -> (White &), RevolutionAxis -> "X"];
gSurface = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[g[x], {x, -5, 1}, {u, 0, 2 π}, 
    ColorFunction -> (White &), RevolutionAxis -> "X"];
Show[
  fSurface, gSurface, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: 3Dplot]

The inner surface of revolution and the volume it encloses

```
inner = 
  Volume @ 
    ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= g[x]^2, {{x, -5, 1}, {y, -24, 24}, {z, -24, 24}}]
```

> `1152 π`

The outer surface of revolution and the volume it encloses

```
outer = 
  Volume @ 
    ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= f[x]^2, {{x, -5, 1}, {y, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}}]
```

`(11376 π)/5`

The volume enclosed between the two surfaces

```
outer - inner
```

> `(5616 π)/5`

Getting the volume by integration (which for this problem is much faster)

```
Integrate[π (f[x]^2 - g[x]^2), {x, -5, 1}]
```

> `(5616 π)/5`

Comment: I edited the post to depict the exact area I want to revolve around the X axis. I'm not sure which one of your plots that is, but I get what the problem is. Those look almost like Klein Bottles in some way. However the last plot looks promising.

Comment: Could you add the syntax used to plot the objects pictured above? I could learn a great deal from it.

Comment: @BlkPengu. I have updated my post to provide the code you asked for and some more that I think will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach (note volume of `RegionDifference` does not seem to work):

```
f[x_] := 4 - x^2
g[x_] := 4 x - 1
region = ImplicitRegion[
   0 < y^2 + z^2 <= Max[f[x]^2, g[x]^2], {{x, -5, 1}, y, z}];
mr = ImplicitRegion[
   0 < y^2 + z^2 <= Min[f[x]^2, g[x]^2], {{x, -5, 1}, y, z}];
ro = RegionDifference[region, mr];
rplot = RegionPlot3D[ro, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6],
    Background -> Black];
rot[a_] := RotationMatrix[a, {1, 0, 0}]
ppl[a_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{rot[a].{x, 0, f[x]}, rot[a].{x, 0, g[x]}}, {x, -5, 
   1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
Manipulate[Show[rplot, ppl[a]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Volume:

```
Through[{Simplify, N}[Volume[region] - Volume[mr]]]
```

yields:

```
{-(8/5) (-394 + 49 Sqrt[7]) π, 1328.81}
```