# Solid of revolution generated with two curves

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions

I'm trying to get the solid of revolution that is generated with two implied curves.The problem say,find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $x=3y^2-2$ and $x=y^2$ about the line $x=1$. I found a very similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134459), note that I did not know use the `RegionPlot3D` command, besides I am not sure if it is the correct command for this case. I hope someone can help me get the 3D graphic that is what interests me. Thanks in advance

[image: curves]

Area in red is what is rotated around the line $x = 1$

[image: red]

Comment: You should look at [`RevolutionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html) and you may find reading [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155401/) and its answers helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a brute-force way.

> 1. Find the line segments from the plot

```
plot = ContourPlot[{(x) == (3 z^2 - 2), (x) == z^2}, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5},
                    MaxRecursion -> 2, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x <= 1]]

pts = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[ps__, __] :> ps, Infinity][[1]];
line = Cases[plot, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
lines = pts[[#]] & /@ line;
Graphics[{Red, Line[lines[[1]]], Blue, Line[lines[[2]]]}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: 2D plot]

> 2. Convert it to 3D points and rotate around any desired point or line

```
out = {#[[1]], 0.0, #[[2]]} & /@ lines[[1]];
in = {#[[1]], 0.0, #[[2]]} & /@ lines[[2]];

angle = Pi/2;
axis = {0, 0, 1};
point = {1, 0, 0};

out1 = Map[RotationTransform[angle, axis, point], out];
in1 = Map[RotationTransform[angle, axis, point], in];

Graphics3D[{Red, Line[out], Line[out1], Blue, Line[in], Line[in1]}]
```

[image: 3D plot]

> 3. Rotate over $2\pi$ solid angle to get full surface

```
out2 = Flatten[Table[Map[RotationTransform[angle,axis,point],out],{angle,0, 2 Pi,0.5}],1];
in2 = Flatten[Table[Map[RotationTransform[angle,axis,point],in],{angle,0, 2 Pi,0.5}], 1];
```

> 4. Use [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html)

```
reg1 = ConvexHullMesh[out2]
reg2 = ConvexHullMesh[in2]
```

[image: surface of revolution]

You can use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) over a region to get the volume (look at [Volume under a List3dPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162532/volume-under-a-list3dplot)).

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ reg1] - NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ reg1]
```

but for your system, you can integrate over the 2D region and multiply with $2\pi$ due to its symmetry.

```
reg[x_, y_] := (x) > (3 y^2 - 2) && (x) < y^2
RegionPlot[reg[x, y], {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
NIntegrate[Boole[reg[x, y]], {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image: region]

> 2.66667

Comment: It is an excellent explanation what you give, thanks for going step by step so it is better understood. I learned about the existence of new mathematica commands so my doubts are solved.

Answer (score 2):

Let's solve the easier problem first:

> Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $x=3y^2-2$ and $x=y^2$ about the line $x=1$.

We can use Pappus's theorem for this. First, set up the region:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[3 y^2 - 2 <= x <= y^2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
```

Visualize:

```
RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image: the region]

Pappus's theorem now proceeds like this:

```
Area[reg] (2 π EuclideanDistance[RegionCentroid[reg], {1, 0}])
   (128 π)/15
```

As a plausibility check, let's compute the volume with a different method:

```
4 π (Integrate[Sqrt[(3 - r)/3] r, {r, 0, 3}] - Integrate[Sqrt[1 - r] r, {r, 0, 1}])
   (128 π)/15
```

(exercise: how did I derive this integral?)

To visualize the solid of revolution itself, we can use `contourRegionPlot3D[]` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530):

```
contourRegionPlot3D[(z^2 - 1)^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= (3 z^2 - 3)^2,
                    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[2/3]]
```

[image: solid of revolution]

(exercise: how did I derive the required inequalities?)